# how to add multiple widgets?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I've a two widgets in my android program and I implementations both of them in to the AndroidManifest but when I put this two widgets in my android screen on a same time , once of them showing me empty and another one works normally.

This is my manifest , is my issue depend to my manifest?

```
   <receiver android:name=".MyMediumWidget" android:label="@string/medium_widget_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/medium_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".MyLargeWidget" android:label="@string/large_widget_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/large_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
```

Thanks

Comment: Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm offering multiple widgets in my app and my manifest declarations are exactly the same as yours, so I would say your issue may be living in your code and not in your manifest.

Hope this helps pal,

-serkan

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Service for updating them be sure both services are declared in the manifest =)

also you should check if in your real code

```
<receiver android:name=".MyMediumWidget" ...
```

and

```
<receiver android:name=".MyLargeWidget" ...
```

Have different classes. Else you'll only see one